# How to set date-axis language of ggplot within lapply?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply, date-formatting

I am having troubles changing the language of a `ggplot` date axis. Normally, I would just use `Sys.setlocale()` and then create the plot. Now I have created a function that does exactly this (among other layout specific changes) and it works just fine. However, when I use this function inside `lapply()` it no longer works. This is really confusing me. Is there any other way to set the date-axis language in `ggplot`?

Here a minimal reproduceable example: (I am working on Windows so it might be necessary for others to change the `locale`-argument in `Sys.setlocale()` inside `ggtheme()`)

```
library( ggplot2 )

# sample data 
df <- data.frame( "Date" = as.Date( c( "2021-04-01",
                                       "2021-04-20",
                                       "2021-05-07",
                                       "2021-05-25" ) ),
                  "Value" = c( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) )

# function to change Date-axis language
ggtheme <- function( plot, language ){
  
  switch( language,
          "EN" = Sys.setlocale( category = "LC_ALL", locale = "english" ),
          "DE" = Sys.setlocale( category = "LC_ALL", locale = "german" ),
          Sys.setlocale( category = "LC_ALL", locale = "english" ) )
  
  plot <- plot
  
  return( plot )
  
}

# check current locale (just as information)
Sys.getlocale()

# lapply to create plots with english and german x-axis (date) labels
ls_plots <- lapply( c( "DE", "EN" ), function( LANGUAGE ){
  
  plot <- ggplot( df, 
                  aes( x = Date, 
                       y = Value ) ) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle( paste( "Here x-axis should be in", LANGUAGE ) )
  
  plot <- ggtheme( plot, language = LANGUAGE )
  
  return( plot )
  
})

names( ls_plots ) <- c( "DE", "EN" )

# output (for DE it should be Mai; for EN it should be May)
ls_plots$DE
ls_plots$EN
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I believe the locale is retrieved and used at the time of rendering the plot, not building it. Therefore, the locale you set during the build process is not referenced.

Comment: Are you amenable to adding the relevant language as a column of the data?

Comment: @r2evans, good point, you are right. The locale is used when rendering the plot...I should have come up with this by myself.

Comment: It's not necessary than as I can just use the `Sys.setlocale()` before producing the SVG's. Thank you so much for helping out!